# setting the minikube flanneld configuration

Tags: minikube, flanneld

I have been starting `minikube` with:

`./minikube start --cni flannel --enable-default-cni  --container-runtime=docker --driver=docker --nodes 3`

However, this does not start the `vxlan` backend.  I need the `vxlan` backend.

`minikube` [should support the vxlan backend now](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1362).

My `flanneld` vxlan config is:

##### flannel-config.json

```json
{
  "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
  "SubnetLen": 24,
  "Backend": {
    "Type": "vxlan",
    "VNI": 1
  }
}
```

How do I apply this `flanneld` configuration when I start the cluster?  Please assume my cluster has not been started yet.